# TYPO3 v7.6.19: solr PHP Warning: failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached

Tags: php, apache, nginx, solr, typo3

I have the issue that I want to use the TYPO3 extension apache "solr" to index the site but getting the Error of solr that the page does many redirects. If I press the button "index now" I getting following logs of solr:

1. TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception: PHP Warning: file_get_contents(https://example.com/index.php?id=29323&L=0): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /var/www/html/typo3conf/ext/solr/Classes/IndexQueue/PageIndexerRequest.php line 404 in /var/www/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Error/ErrorHandler.php:111
2. log from nginx https access log: 
    2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:34 +0200] "GET

   /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 200 87 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:35 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:35 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:35 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:36 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:36 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:36 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:37 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:37 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:37 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

   2001:67c:2090::1:bbd - - [22/Jun/2017:18:59:37 +0200] "GET /index.php?id=29323&L=0 HTTP/1.0" 303 0 "-" "TYPO3/7.6.19"

Because of the Redirects solr cannot index the pages. I want to know why this is happening. Is it an issue from solr-extension, TYPO3 or on the server or how could I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It was a Content Element which is connected to OAuth2. For some reason Ext:solr does a call to Custom Content Element to parsing it. So every time it try´s to  call it, it gets redirected in a loop. So to solve it i used the Headers. If Typo3 header is called and not a browser it should not parse this Content Element.
So i just removed this Element from parsing it.

Comment: also the timeout was a problem, because if you test the timeoutvalue it isn´t that what i had set. check also your timeout value in FileGetContents.php which will set by the performGetRequest method.

Answer (score 0):

Any WAF around? HTACCESS unmodified? Varnish?

Comment: no htaccess we are using nginx. for WAF i have to ask. i will tell you then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP redirections it is because they can't be sent at any time but you can switch them with javascript redirections and it works without any problem